# How to identify blank hostname in my network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I share the Internet with my neighbour, but it's mine. He asked me to do it since he couldn't ask for his own (Venezuela's things).

There's an ethernet wire that goes from my router to his house and he was connecting a laptop there and some Android devices from wireless.

But one day I had a slow connection. I checked the `DHCP` list and I identified a router connected through the cable. This wasn't good since I couldn't have control of who is connected to my network so I called him in order to disconnect it.

These days I've been experiencing the same but when I check the `DHCP` list, I find that the `hostname` in the LAN connection is just a blank field, so I assumed, he erased it in his router and connected it again so that I couldn't figure out.

I blocked him but I want to be sure that it was his router. Is there a way to identify this device??

Comment: Add to your router's black-list the MAC address of that router and wait for reaction ...

Comment: @harrymc I did it! But what I want to know if certify my thoughts... maybe he can come at me with something like "It's my pc!!" and I can't prove against

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be sure it's your neighbor's router that is hiding behind the
blank name, set your router to not accept unknown MAC addresses, and enter
the MAC addresses of all your devices in the allowed list.

Depending on your router, the easiest way to do that may be to disable the option,
connect your devices, then add them to the allowed list from the router's
interface.

Ask your neighbor for his MAC address and add it to the list.
You can then be sure of not having any uninvited piggy-back visitors.

If your router supports Quality of Service (QoS), you may limit
your neighbor's portion of your bandwidth and solve the problem.

Comment: I have added one more paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If your router shows the MAC address of the connected device you can use a site like: https://macvendors.com/ to find out what vendor that MAC address belongs to. This may give a hint of what device is connected. The first three pairs of an MAC address are vendor specific while the last 3 are device specific.

Comment: Samsung Electronics Co. Do samsung do routers?

Comment: They apparently have this mesh WiFi Router https://www.samsung.com/us/smart-home/smartthings-wifi/ However they have a lot of registered mac address spaces.(https://gist.github.com/aallan/b4bb86db86079509e6159810ae9bd3e4) It might help if you google the first three groups, maybe you will find some forum posts or something like that from people finding such a devices in there network.

Comment: Keep in mind MAC addresses can be forged.

Comment: Well the question was if the neighbor connected his router of unknown brand. While its theoretically possible to spoof the mac with costume firmware (are there manufacturer that offer mac address changing with there default firmware?) it's questionable if the neighbor has the knowledge and / or willpower to do so.